# LINQ: How to join IEnumerable<SomeType> into object with SomeType properties?

Tags: linq, join

I have an `IEnumerable<byte>` which I want to transform to `new object { byte property1, byte property2, ....}`, to join all those byte values into one object.

How I do that using LINQ?

Comment: They already are in one object. Call `.ToArray()` and then you can index into the values.

Comment: Why do you want to create an anonymous type that contains all properties from your byte-list? You could access each byte via indexer even if you store the complete collection only.

Comment: b/c I made the collection of an object choosing only properties of type byte, like this: IEnumerable<byte> tacticbyte = tactic.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetValue(tactic) is byte).Select(p => (byte)p.GetValue(tactic));

So I want those byte properties together in new type

Answer (score 0):

**I have no idea why you'd like to achieve that**, but I think there is a way, using [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) from `System.Dynamics`.

It can be done using `Aggregate` method from LINQ:

```
return source.Select((x, i) => new {name = string.Format("{0}{1}", propertyPrefix, i), value = x})
                .Aggregate((new ExpandoObject()) as IDictionary<string, Object>,
                        (e, i) =>
                            {
                                e[i.name] = i.value;
                                return e;
                            }, e => e as ExpandoObject);
```

You should hide it under another extension method, like `ToExpandoObject`:

```
public static ExpandoObject ToExpandoObject<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, string propertyPrefix)
{
    return source.Select((x, i) => new {name = string.Format("{0}{1}", propertyPrefix, i), value = x})
                    .Aggregate((new ExpandoObject()) as IDictionary<string, Object>,
                            (e, i) =>
                                {
                                    e[i.name] = i.value;
                                    return e;
                                }, e => e as ExpandoObject);
}
```

Usage:

```
var source = new List<int>() {123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678};

var t = source.ToExpandoObject("Property");
```